# .BAT - opening a program stops the bat file executing the next line

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wont bore you with all the details of why I need to do this, but basically I am trying to run a couple of commands within a batch file, however when I run something like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"
```

it pauses the execution. So unless I then close down excel, the program will not continue.

if someone could help me to get the below program to work, I would be very grateful (the concept is to tell my computer to run EXCEL, wait 5 seconds and then run WORD:

```
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"

TIMEOUT /5

CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WORD.EXE"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Start`:

```bat
Start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"
Timeout 5 >Nul
Start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Office16\WINWORD.EXE"
```

*Depending upon your `%PATH%` and `%PATHEXT%` variable values and entries in the [App Paths](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2010/08/how-the-app-paths-registry-key-makes-windows-both-faster-and-safer/) registry keys, you could probably even leave out the paths and extensions:*

```bat
Start Excel
Timeout 5 >Nul
Start WinWord
```

Answer (score -3):

Replace `call` with `start` and it will work.

Comment: @weBBer It is a correct answer. So it does provide an answer. Also you do not seem to be experienced in this area.

Comment: @CatCat It is an answer, but it is not only too short, it also falls short ignoring the fact that `start` will interpret the first quoted argument as the window title - thus a simple replacement of call for start won't work. See Compo's correct and more complete answer.

Comment: @LotPings The comment was **it does not provide an answer**. It does even if sub optimal.

Comment: @weBBer: It does in fact provide an answer. It may not be the most well written of the answers, but it makes an attempt at answering the question.

Comment: @CatCat: Tone it down. It's unnecessary. Please be polite.

Comment: all the feedback's appreciated